# Azure Service Bus Topic Else Subscriber

Tags: azure-servicebus-topics

When you send a message to a topic, if there is no subscription with a matching filter, the message gets lost.

How can I avoid this without creating a subscription that basically negates all the existing filters?

I don't want to lose messages, and if one comes without a subscriber, I want someone to look at it to see why that happened. I don't want this logic in the sender because the sender shouldn't be aware of subscribers.

I would like to avoid having to constantly update this "else subscriber" (ex, adding, deleting subscription).

Any ideas?

Comment: Seems like a request for this was already created: https://github.com/Azure/azure-service-bus/issues/277

Answer (score 1):

It would be nice if one could take subscriptions created with their rules, negate the rules and concatenate to the "else" type of subscription you're asking for. Unfortunately, there's no easy negation. And multiple rules are evaluated using OR logic, not AND. So the rules today are based on the accepting criteria only.

This is an interesting feature request you could raise with the Azure Service Bus team [here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-service-bus/issues).
`